# Catching invalid method arguments using assert

Tags: java

I am slightly confused regarding assert.

I have a constructor for a Circular array where the capacity of the array obviously could not be negative as a negative length for an array is invalid. I am aware I could set the value myself if it is invald or throw an exception but I've also seen assert used to prevent invalid input (specifically in C) so I tried following.

Constructor (excluding all the unnecessary parameters that also is initialized):
Note,  `Message` is simply a class that holds a string.

```
    public CircularArray(int capacity)
{
    assert capacity > 0 : "Array capacity violated, precondition argument > 0";
    elements = new Message[capacity];
}
```

and if I run it with -ea the assertion is indeed displayed however I still recieve what seems to be an error or trying to initialize an array with an invalid length. Is this how it's supposed to look or do I have to something additional?

Also, since assertions are turned off by default, would it be better to instead throw and exception as follows:

```
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

To clarify, the terminal output yields:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Array capacity violated, precondition argument > 0`

`at CircularArray.<init>(CircularArray.java:19)`

`at CircularArray.main(CircularArray.java:98)`

Maybe this is the correct output but it felt a bit strange that it clarified what where the errors are generated by specifying what lines of code.

Comment: *"however I still recieve what seems to be an error or trying to initialize an array with an invalid length"* - what else did you expect? You wrote code to make an error when the length is invalid, and you get an error when the length is invalid. I don't see how this differs from what you thought the program should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

> Also, since assertions are turned off by default, would it be better to instead throw and exception as follows:
>
> ```
> throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
> ```

Yes, that’s precisely what [the guidelines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#usage) say:

> - Do *not* use assertions for argument checking in public methods.
>
>   Argument checking is typically part of the published specifications (or *contract*) of a method, and these specifications must be obeyed whether assertions are enabled or disabled. Another problem with using assertions for argument checking is that erroneous arguments should result in an appropriate runtime exception (such as `IllegalArgumentException`, `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, or `NullPointerException`). An assertion failure will not throw an appropriate exception.

But the most appropriate exception would be `IllegalArgumentException` in your case, as the specified number is not an index. This is what standard collection constructors, e.g. `ArrayList(int initialCapacity)`, also use. Note that it is uses an exception message like `"Illegal Capacity: " + initialCapacity`, including the actual illegal value, which you might consider as well.

The `assert` statement is for checking invariants which should be fulfilled by application logic anyway, so that turning the checks off should make no difference, at least in theory (they may make a difference in practice due to bugs, which is what these checks are all about).

Answer (score 0):

This is how assert works :

```
assert condition : expression
```

When it fails, it passes the `expression` as parameter of the `AssertionException` and throws it.

Since assertion is turned off by default it would be better to use a different handling to have more flexibility on the target platforms where it's supposed to run on.

example using IndexOutOfBoundsException :

```
public CircularArray(int capacity) {
  if (capicity <= 0) {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Array capacity violated, precondition argument > 0");
  }
  elements = new Message[capacity];
}
```

If you feel like IndexOutOfBoundsException is not the right Exception to be thrown you can replace it by another one or even create a  custom one :

```
    public class CircularArrayInitialisationException extends Exception {

      public CircularArrayInitialisationException (String message, Throwable cause, ErrorCode code) {
          super(message, cause);
          this.code = code;
      }
      ...
  }
```